# Зачем Composer требует personal access token от github? Как можно сделать так, чтоб не требовал?

Tags: github, composer

Собственно в вопросе все сказал. Из документации понял только то, что он нужен, но зачем, понять не смог. Могу ли я пользоваться composer-ом, если я не зарегистрирован на github?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чисто гипотетически, да.

Однако следует учесть, что в некоторых случаях Composer не может получить нужные файлы из-за [ограничений на количество запросов](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting) к API GitHub. Токен решает эту проблему.

Для неавторизованных запросов этот лимит равен 60 запросам в час. Лимит привязывается к IP, а не к пользователю, сделавшему запрос.

Отвечу сразу и на второй вопрос: чтобы Composer (на самом деле GitHub) не требовал токен, нужно придерживаться указанного лимита.